# How do I apply more than one conditional formatting rule using JSON to a SP Online List column?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have two calculated columns Variance and Variance %, they both have conditional formatting (via the SP Design Space) to turn the background green when they are less then $10K and 10% respectively.

I would like to also change the font red when the number is negative. How do I add to the JSON for this to happen?

Comment: Can you share your existing JSON code? I will update the same to add 2nd condition then post complete JSON as an answer. OR you can try to add code in my answer to your existing JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot apply multiple JSON formatting codes to single column. So, you have to manage multiple conditions/rules within same JSON.

For changing color to red when number is negative, add below code in your existing JSON:

```
...

"style": {
      "color": "=if(@currentField < 0, 'red', '#323130')"
}

...
```

**Documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

Comment: THANK YOU Ganesh Sanap!!

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future.